# suming an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

the question involves person A eating half a loaf of bread. then person B eats half of the half left over. then person A eats half of whats left over... etc. I defined the series of person A as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n-1}}$ and person B as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^{2n}}$. How would you sum the 2 series separately so you know how much person A ate and how much person B ate?

Comment: Your sums are set up correctly. Hint: These are geometric series.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Just note that $S_B = \frac12 S_A$, and $S_A+ S_B=1$.  Can you finish it?

Answer (score 1):

For person $B$ you have:
$$
\sum_{n \ge 1} 2^{-2 n} = 2^{-2} \sum_{n \ge 0} 4^{-n}
                        = \frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{1}{1 - 1 / 4}
                        = \frac{1}{3}
$$
so person $A$ gets:
$$
1 - \frac{1}{3} = \frac{2}{3}
$$

Comment: You should endeavor to give hints for homework, not just explicitly solve the problem. The student learns nothing from a solution except how to copy.